# Updated book/chapter or review article with broad perspective on computational chemistry

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, reference-request, drug-design

I really like Frank Jensen's "Introduction to Computational Chemistry" because it provides a broad perspective, starting from first principles and extending to surveys of current methods for Monte Carlo, molecular dynamics, etc. However, this book is from 2017, and many new directions are not covered (for example, machine learning driven methods, quantum computing related methods, and computational methods to address chemical synthesis). Is there a recommendation for recent books, book chapters, review articles, etc., that cover the important new directions in a way that is accessible for non-experts, especially in applications related to drug discovery and medicinal chemistry?